# auth.onAuthStateChanged not triggering after auth.currentUser.updateProfile in Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a component updating the user's profile pic:

```js
const Updater = () => {

    const updateProfilePic = async (photoURL) => {

        await auth.currentUser.updateProfile({ 'photoURL': photoURL });

    }

}
```

I have a second component detecting changes in the user's state:

```js
const StateChangesDetector = () => {

    auth.onAuthStateChanged( user => {

        if(user)
            console.log('User changed state', JSON.stringify(user));

    });

}
```

The problem is that `auth.onAuthStateChanged()` is not triggering after the execution of `updateProfile()`. Thus, I'm getting the old user's state and the old profile picture.

How can I force to trigger `auth.onAuthStateChanged()` after updating the user's profile picture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [reload()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#reload) function on the currentUser object to get updated information.  Note that it's asynchronous and returns a promise.  If it doesn't trigger the listener (as it's not really a "state" change, just a refresh of data), I suspect you might have to access the `firebase.auth().currentUser` again after the returned promise resolves to see new data.